# Is @Query("SELECT * FROM info_table where translateState != ETranslateState.COMPLETED ORDER BY createdDate desc") correct?

Tags: android, android-room

In Android Studio, I use the *Room* framework to create and operate database.

I hope to query all columns (*) from the `info_table` where the `translateState` column is not equal to `ETranslateState.COMPLETED`.

I am not sure whether the code `@Query("SELECT * FROM info_table where translateState != ETranslateState.COMPLETED ORDER BY createdDate desc")` is correct in the `interface RecordDao {... }`, could you tell me?

**Added Content:**

I get the following error!

*There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such column: ETranslateState.COMPLETED)
public abstract kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow<java.util.List<com.hicalc.soundrecorder.domain.model.MInfo>> listAllExceptIncompleted();*

```
@Dao
interface  RecordDao {  
    @Query("SELECT * FROM info_table where translateState != ETranslateState.COMPLETED ORDER BY createdDate desc")
    fun listAllExceptIncompleted(): Flow<List<MInfo>>
}


@Entity(tableName = "info_table", indices = [Index("createdDate")])
data class RecordEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = "id") var id: Int = 0,   
    var createdDate:     Calendar = Calendar.getInstance(),
    var translateState:  ETranslateState = ETranslateState.PENDING
)

class DBConvert {
    @TypeConverter
    fun calendarToDatestamp(calendar: Calendar): Long = calendar.timeInMillis

    @TypeConverter
    fun datestampToCalendar(value: Long): Calendar =  Calendar.getInstance().apply { timeInMillis = value }

    @TypeConverter
    fun eTranslateStateToInteger(eTranslateState: ETranslateState):Int = eTranslateState.ordinal

    @TypeConverter
    fun integerToETranslateState(index:Int): ETranslateState = ETranslateState.values()[index]
}

enum class ETranslateState {
    PENDING,
    PROCESSING,
    ERROR,
    COMPLETED
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:-

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM info_table where translateState != :etrans ORDER BY createdDate desc")
fun listAllExceptIncompleted(etrans: ETranslateState = ETranslateState.COMPLETED): Flow<List<MInfo>>
```

Comment: Tnanks! `An annotation argument must be a compile-time constant` will be displayed, and can't be compiled when I use  `@Query("SELECT * FROM info_table where translateState != ${ETranslateState.COMPLETED} ORDER BY createdDate desc")`

Comment: And more,  `@Query("SELECT * FROM info_table where translateState != :etrans ORDER BY createdDate desc")` can be compiled, but I don't know if it can run OK

Comment: @HelloCW if you look at the generated java for the class `RecordDao_Impl` I believe that you will see that within the processing of the function `listAllExceptIncompleted` that it invokes the `eTranslateStateToInteger` function i.e. converts and binds the value so the Int is used. I did run a test an checked.

Comment: @HelloCW follow on from previous comment as per:- `public List<TheTable> searchSingleValue(final String singleSearchValue,
      final ETranslateState etrans) {
    final String _sql = "SELECT id,? AS theColumn FROM thetable WHERE thecolumn LIKE '%'||?||'%' OR theColumn  != ?";
    final RoomSQLiteQuery _statement = RoomSQLiteQuery.acquire(_sql, 3);
    int _argIndex = 1;
    final int _tmp = __dBConvert.eTranslateStateToInteger(etrans);` ***(used existing code to test hence the funny query)***

Comment: @HelloCW for the previous comment, the function in the `@Dao` annotated class being:- `@Query("SELECT id,:etrans AS theColumn FROM thetable WHERE thecolumn LIKE '%'||:singleSearchValue||'%' OR theColumn  != :etrans")
    fun searchSingleValue(singleSearchValue: String, etrans: ETranslateState = ETranslateState.COMPLETED): List<TheTable>`

Comment: Thank you very much , I test it again, `An annotation argument must be a compile-time constant` will be displayed, and can't be compiled when I use `@Query("SELECT * FROM info_table where translateState != ${ETranslateState.COMPLETED} ORDER BY createdDate desc")`

Comment: @HelloCW Use **only** the second where the you code the value in the parameter of the function. Answer updated to reflect this.